# How to find the size of the ArcGIS map when the map takes up less space than the containing div (zoom=0)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I've been digging through the ArcGIS map trying to figure out how to find the size of the map. The map object has width / height but those are the containing div and not the width / height of the current map. Is there a way to find / calculate the width / height of the map?

Answer (score 0):

using Spatial Reference of 4326 (GPS coords)

I was able to find the width of the map using

```
var left = new Point(-180, 0)
  var right = new Point(180, 0)

  var leftScreenPoint = map.toScreen(left); //ScreenUtils.toScreenPoint(map.extent, map.width, map.height, left);
  var rightScreenPoint = map.toScreen(right);
```

basically I get the screen point for the far left, and screen point for the far right and then subtract right from left to get the map width